# How do I automate two layers of SSH plus a docker exec?

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, automation

I do this multiple times a day. Any clues on automating it, so that I can run one command to get all the way to the logs? There are two `ssh` and then a `docker exec`.

`➜  ~ ssh host
Last login: Tue Jun 27 15:44:11 2017 from 10.82.34.63
$ ssh another-host
Last login: Tue Jun 27 15:44:18 2017 from host
$ docker exec -it app-container bash
[root@app-container opt]# tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: Is the first host always the same?

Comment: Yes it's always `host`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: it's indeed off-topic. But instead of voting down, I'd suggest to vote for migration...

Comment: Does "voting to close off topic" and then selecting a site trigger the migration? The UI is unclear that this actually migrates instead of closes.

Comment: @AndyShinn AFAIK, it get's moderator attention and whether it *is* migrated depends on the quality of the question. As this question seems quite clear, I'd expect it to be migrated after closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least a partial answer for `ssh`. Look at `ssh` usage output:

```
ssh (.... lots of options ....) [user@]hostname [command]
```

So, there's an optional `command` at the end of the argument list, after the required `hostname`. This indeed works as you would expect, you can "*chain*" another `ssh` command here that's executed remote:

```
ssh host ssh another-host
```

will do.

Note that your `ssh` will not allocate a `tty` in this case, so it will not enable you to have an *interactive* session. But of course, you can give this *second* `ssh` something to execute as well

```
ssh host ssh another-host docker exec [...]
```

---

For the last part, I just looked up the docker documentation. The option `-t` requires a `tty`, so you should leave it out. Then you should be able to execute whatever you like in your container, as long as it's nothing *interactive*:

```
ssh host ssh another-host docker exec -i app-container tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

---

Of course, for full automation, use [SSH keys](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) and have an [SSH agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) running with your key added.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I tried `ssh host ssh another-host docker exec -it app-container tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out` yet I get an error: `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input` nor can I execute `pwd` at the end of the tail.

Comment: @bgoosman or, if you **need** interaction (you don't need it for a simple `tail`), see [AndyShinn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44809832/2371524) how to force SSH to allocate a `tty`.

Answer (score 2):

We can take advantage of `ProxyCommand` in OpenSSH for the first part (jumping through a proxy host to SSH to others). An example for your `~/.ssh/config` would look like:

```
Host another-host
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p host
    HostName another-host
```

If all the hosts that you are proxying through happened to be in the same domain you could catch a bunch of them with a wildcard:

```
Host jumphost
    Hostname host.mydomain

Host *.mydomain
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
```

For the second part, there is no need to `exec` into the container with a shell before using a command. Doing `docker exec -it app-container tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out` is perfectly valid.

Combined with the SSH configuration, you can allocate a pseudo TTY (`-t`) and then just do one command:

```
ssh -t another-host docker exec -it app-container tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Comment: +1 for showing some nice ssh features (including the option to enable tty). OP won't need this for a simple `tail`, but maybe later for other things :)